# Why is reject not working on my Hash even though the condition is true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash, rails-console

I have the following hash

```
{"goes_by"=>[nil, ""], "middle_name"=>[nil, ""], "suffix"=>[nil, ""], "jersey"=>["8", "8A"]}
```

I'm trying to write a statement to reject any elements that have a nested array with nil & "".  So I wrote the following command to try and perform this but it returns `nil` as if there weren't any changes to the hash...

```
Player.find(286).audits.first.audited_changes.reject! {|x| x[1][0].blank? && x[1][1].blank? }
         => nil
```

but when I print out the results the condition is true for three of the elements. What am I missing here?

```
Player.find(286).audits.first.audited_changes.each {|x| puts x[1][0].blank? && x[1][1].blank? }

    true
    true
    true
    false

     => {"goes_by"=>[nil, ""], "middle_name"=>[nil, ""], "suffix"=>[nil, ""], "jersey"=>["8", "8A"]}
```

Comment: Does `#audited_changes` build the hash or access an instance variable?

Comment: instance variable, it's stored as part of the record to my understanding. If it helps it's part of the gem `audited`.

Comment: Ok, so `#reject!` will only remove the elements from the instance variable; it won't do any updates in the database. You're reaching back into the database to verify that the operation worked, which returns a new ruby object with fresh values from the database.

Try holding onto the player instance, and saving it after the reject:

`player = Player.find(286)`;  
`player.audits.first.audited_changes.reject! { #... }`;  
`player.audits.first.save`  ;

Comment: if `{:goes_by=>[nil, ""], :middle_name=>[nil, ""], :suffix=>[nil, ""], :jersey=>["8", "8A"]}` this is your hash then `hash.values.reject!{|x| x[0].nil? && x[1].empty?}` should work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all, when you call `reject!` on a hash remember that your block should take two parameters not one. In your case parameter `x` is always a key of your hash so respectively: goes_by, middle_name, suffix,

so the block should look like this:

`.reject! { |key, array| array.all? { |array_item| array_item.blank? } }`

Comment: If `#reject!` is called with a block that takes a single argument, each key/value pair is yielded as a 2 element array.

Comment: This worked nicely and improved on my ugly code thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that you are using [reject!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#reject-method) with a hash

```
{ "goes_by"=>[nil, ""],
  "middle_name"=>[nil, ""], 
  "suffix"=>[nil, ""],
  "jersey"=>["8", "8A"]
}.reject! {|key, value| value.all?(&:blank?) }]
```

This will return => {"jersey"=>["8", "8A"]}